# How to override the functionality of the close button in chained dialog boxes in jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, overriding, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

In jQuery Mobile I have several chained dialog boxes sliding in/out one after another when inputs were made and 'next'-buttons were clicked. But any time the close-button inside the header of the dialog box is clicked I want to get back to the initial page where the first dialog box was triggered. Normally the close button in each dialog box leads back to the page/box it was triggered from. But in my app I need to override them all to get back to the first page!

My code:

```
<div class="ui-block-b">
    <a data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" 
        data-transition="slide" href="nextpage.html" data-rel="dialog">
        next
    </a>
</div>
```

thnx!

edit: The docs say

> CHAINING DIALOGS: "Please note: If a dialog opens another dialog (chaining), closing the
>   last one with a link of type data-rel="back" will always navigate to
>   the previous dialog until the root-page of type data-role="page" is
>   reached. This guarantees a consistent navigation between dialogs."
>   [http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-beta.1/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html]

Comment: Hi! Can you provide your code?

Comment: there is no special code. it's a simple page with some elements and a button to open the next dialog box like `<div class="ui-block-b"><a data-role="button" data-theme="b"  data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-transition="slide" href="nextpage.html"  data-rel="dialog">next</a></div>`.

Comment: ups - thanx for editing! I just came back to move the codeblock into the question by myself... sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the close method defined for the dialogs `$.mobile.dialog.prototype.close`:

```
<script>

    $.mobile.dialog.prototype.close = function(){

        console.log("close");

        // DO SOMETHING HERE - EX: REDIRECTING TO MAIN PAGE
        $.mobile.changePage("index.html");
    };

    $(function() {
        console.log("document loaded");         
    });

</script>
```

Comment: great, thanx! do you also know how toprevent stacking the "&ui-state=dialog&ui-state=dialog..." to the URL of chained dialogs?

Comment: Your welcome :). I think you cannot prevent the stacking of url, this is related to the navigation :S... Why do you want to get rid of it?

Comment: because I want to chain about 15 dialogs and the ugly url seems absolutely unnecessary when I won't use the history back functionality. :-)

Comment: What you can try is to add `rel=external` to the links which open the dialogs. This attribute will disable the ajax navigation. You can have a try. Normally you wouldn't have added content in your url with this method. :)

Comment: coolI will try.... thnx! [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843852/how-to-prevent-stacking-the-url-of-chained-dialogs-in-jquery-mobile/12852068#12852068]