# How to prevent stacking the URL of chained dialogs in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, overriding, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

When you chain dialog boxes in jQuery Mobile there are these "&ui-state=dialog&ui-state=dialog..." strings stacked on the URL. Is there a way to prevent this?

Thnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- What you can try is to add `rel=external` to the links which open the dialogs. 

  This attribute will disable the Ajax navigation and should prevent stacking the URL.
- You could also try the `pushState plugin`:

> There is an optional feature that converts the longer, hash-based URLs
>   mentioned in the previous section into the full document path which is
>   cleaner and makes the Ajax tracking transparent in the URL structure.
>   This is built as an enhancement on top of the hash-based URL system
>   for Ajax links. Note that despite the name, this feature technically
>   converts hash-based URLs by using **history.replaceState** (not
>   **history.pushState**) in the current release because this works more
>   reliably across our target platforms. For browsers that do not support
>   **history.replaceState**, or if this feature is disabled, hash-based URLs
>   will be used instead.
>
> Since the plugin initializes when the DOM is fully loaded you can
>   enable and disable it manually by setting **$.mobile.pushStateEnabled**
>   global configuration option to **false** anytime before document ready.

You can check the online doc for more information:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html

Comment: with $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false; this seems to work. thnx! but the long URL still remains.